# Count Row and Column in Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, pivot-table

Hi I have a sheet that collects the following

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Name + Address + Borough + Postcode + Date Added +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 John   blah..    London    XX12 XXX   21/01/2012
 Roger  blah..    Surrey    ZZ14 ZZZ   18/02/2013
 Mary   blah..    Surrey    EE17 EEE   18/02/2013
 Helen  blah..    Hackney   VV25 VVV   19/05/2014
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

And I have a Pivot Table with `Borough` as the Column and `Date Added` as the row (which ive grouped into months & years), which makes something like this:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Date Added + London + Hackney + Surrey +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 2012       +        +         +        +
+    Jan     +        +         +        +
+ 2013       +        +         +        +
+    Feb     +        +         +        +
+ 2014       +        +         +        +
+    May     +        +         +        +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

My question is how do I make it count or display the figures from the data for example like this below as my current table shows blank fields like above?

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Date Added + London + Hackney + Surrey +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 2012       +        +         +        +
+    Jan     +    1   +    0    +    0   +
+ 2013       +        +         +        +
+    Feb     +    0   +    0    +    2   +
+ 2014       +        +         +        +
+    May     +    0   +    1    +    0   +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: have you tried putting "Name" in the values field

Answer (score 1):

In the values field for the [pivot table](https://support.office.com/client/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576), you need to insert what you want to sum or count. Then click it to select what calculation you want it to perform (sum, count, etc).

[image]

Comment: Hm, a downvote more than 2 years later..

Answer (score 1):

I was confused by the previous answer, so here's finally worked for me. I had data original data like so:

```
01/01/2015     /r/foo
01/01/2015     /r/foo
01/02/2016     /r/bar
```

And so on, and I created a pivot-table that look like so:

```
             /r/foo     /r/bar      /r/fizz
01/01/2015
01/02/2016
```

And I wanted to count each instance of each row per month. In your pivot table field, right-click the value that you want to sum the instances of like so:

[image]

And it filled in my chart:

```
             /r/foo     /r/bar    /r/fizz
01/01/2015        2          0          0
01/02/2016        0          1          0
```